# Catch Dojo module order loading errors?

Tags: syntax, dojo, jslint

When loading modules it's important to make sure to set your vars up right...

[ "module1", "module2" ], function( module2, module1 )

In this instance, Dojo Module 1 will end up instant instead inside variable 'module2' which is opposite of the desired action.

Is this something that can be caught with JSLint? Or some other tool?

Comment: could you explore the problem a little more? The question and the description doesn't fit well together. That are 2 separate problems.

Comment: You could write you own rules with ESlint but i think your not going to find anything out-of-box for this. One normally needs to be able to define the variable names used in a function. Sometimes you need shorter names then the module names or the names contain characters that can't be used in variable names like slashes etc. You could take a look at ESlint and custom rules: http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules

Comment: @iH8 I will look into ESLINT. I appreciate the pointer...